# Simulink Rsim executable libmx.dll missing

Tags: matlab, executable, simulink

I want to generate a standalone executable for a Simulink model using MATLAB 2010b 32-bit. My ultimate aim is to have a stanalone executable of a package of M-scripts, GUIs and a simulink model with tunable parameters.

I have tried generating an exe using the Rapid simulation target. It works when I call it from a Matlab script using

```
!Modelname.mdl
```

If I run the exe file outside MATLAB, i get the error message:

> "The program cannot be started as the libmx.dll is missing from the
>   computer."

I have checked and all the required DLLs exist in my system at the path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB_Runtime_v7141_r10bSP1\v7141\bin\win32".

Is there a solution for this or are Rsim executables not meant to be used outside MATLAB environment? 
I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I have also tried using Generic real time target (grt) instead of Rsim for building the model's exe file. This works outside Matlab environment without any problem. However, I can not find any documentation about changing the parameter values and input signal in grt exes.

Answer (score 0):

Is your model variable step?

In more recent releases RSIM generated executables are only able to run on machines that have a MATLAB (and Simulink) license installed on them.

In earlier releases you could run RSIM executables on machines that did not have a MATLAB license, but only if the model uses a fixed-step solver.
(I can't remember when the change occurred.)

Comment: Hi Phil. I am using a fixed-step solver. I think you are right. RSIM cannot be used on a computer without Matlab & Simulink. Normally it should still work on my system as I have both. But I am using network-shared licenses. So possibly that is why I cannot run the exe outside Matlab